# flowtype seems to think that Object.keys output is always an array of strings, even if it knows better

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Example code:

```
/* @flow */

type Key = 'a' | 'b';

const obj: {[key: Key]: number} = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

const val = obj[keys[0]];
```

Which [produces this error message](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDSeWYAvGAOQCGlYAPlQEaUDc6AxnAHYDOGYOEwBWALjABvANoBrEuOJYAuuO4BXALZM8AJwC+5SajBhq4gIwAaY2CbiATNb3tUXPgLlZehgPIi8HBgAdJ68ABRCwgCULm78YABu1DCGkbIkvFIADEpK7EA):

```
10: const keys = Object.keys(obj);
                             ^ string. This type is incompatible with
5: const obj: {[key: Key]: number} = {
                     ^ string enum
```

So it thinks `keys` is `string[]` rather than `Key[]`, which seems wrong to me. Is there any way for me to work around this, besides changing `obj`'s type to `{[key: string]: number}`?

Answer (score 2):

Flow raises an error because `Array<T>` is invariant (see https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2487). This can be fixed by defining your own `keys` function

```
function keys<T: string>(obj: any): Array<T> {
  return Object.keys(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, that demonstrates that Flow is correct:

```
type Key = 'a' | 'b';

const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const obj2: { a: number, b: number } = obj1;

const obj: {[key: Key]: number} = obj2;

const keys = Object.keys(obj); // this will be ['a', 'b', 'c']

const val = obj[keys[0]];
```

Comment: Interesting. Why does the first assignment of `obj2` work without an error, since `obj1` has a property `c`?

Comment: because `{ a: number, b: number, c: number }` is a subtype of `{ a: number, b: number }`

Comment: Is there any way to prevent that, like if I wanted an object to only ever have certain keys?

Comment: Ah, I see [this](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#exact-object-types) in the documentation, and it does make it work if I define obj as  {| a: number, b: number |}, but I can't seem to get it to work with the [key: Key] syntax: https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDSeWYAvGAOQCGlYAPlQEaUDc6AxnAHYDOGYOEwBWALjABvRgG0A1iXHEsAXXHcArgFsmeAE4MAvuUmowYauICMAGlNgm4gEy2D7VFz4D5WXsYDyIngcGAB03rwAFELCAJRuHvxgAG7UMMbRciS80gAMysqsQA